# Save / Resume Progress of HTML Application Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a large form containing over 100 fields.  There are again a few dynamically generated fields where users may add multiple records so there is a fair bit of JavaScript / Jquery involved.

Which approaches should I consider to save such a form, and repopulate all these fields.

1)  Serialize the object.  In the end I am currently saving this large form in a serialized object upon click of the "Save" button.  However, thinking about the amount of coding involved to regenerate all these dynamically generated fields/tables upon "Resume", I am wondering about a second approach.

2) Store all the HTML within the form tags.  Just using an AJAX call, pass all the contents (including dynamic structures) into the DB.  It seems it would be easier to access the object using JQuery and repopulate the form upon "Resume".  However, I have not tested this out yet.

Any insight/tips on how others have gotten around this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at BackboneJS as it will make storing and moving the data about a lot simpler for you.

Their are a couple of intro books on backbone that will teach you all the basics you need to know in a day or two.

Comment: Thanks David. I have implemented my project above using ASP.NET MVC, so I see many similarities in the way data is moved from the View to DB and vice versa to that of Bakcbone.js.
I am already able to store my model and can pick up changes, my main issue is taking the data from the DB and re-populating these dynamically created structures (input fields / tables / buttons).  I'm still reading the documentation, hope its able to help me recreate these dynamic structures

Comment: If you make the names of your html fields match the names in your model, you should be able to write a simple loop to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage or sessionStorage to store the responses. Here is a simple example that stores an array of name and value. On save it pushes everything to the available storage, on restore in get's the array from local storage and sets the inputs value to the saved data.

No ajax request needed.

> does not work on stack due to "no same-origin-policy in iframe"

```js
$(function() {
  var $form = $('#form'),
    $save = $('#save'),
    $restore = $('#restore'),
    results = [],
    storage = window.localStorage || window.sessionStorage;

  $form.on('change', 'input[type=text]', function(e) {
    results = $form.serializeArray();
    console.log( 'change', results );
  });

  $save.on('click', function(e) {
    storage.setItem('form-inputs', JSON.stringify(results));
    $form.reset();
  });

  $restore.on('click', function(e) {
    var inputs = JSON.parse( storage.getItem('form-inputs'))
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      $( '[name=' + input.name + ']' ).val( input.value );
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="bar" />
  <input type="button" id="save" value="save" />
  <input type="button" id="restore" value="restore" />
</form>
```